# user can enter in text box just numbers and this signs (, .)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict user to enter in text box just numbers and this signs (, .) when the user try to enter letters or other signs textbox can't accept them How can I do that with jquery?

Comment: And the question is, what have you tried?

Comment: use the regex `/[0-9,.]/`

Comment: I want to enter number like that 1,120.00 to save in database

Comment: check this also http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/1593/

Comment: @VinodVT That's wrong. `|| e.which != 109` prohibits everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9,.]+" title="Please enter only numbers" />
```

No jQuery needed. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C8vbg/)

If you're actually looking for an optionally thousand-separated decimal number, try:

```
pattern="(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})+|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]+)?"
```

[Advanced demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C8vbg/1/)

Be sure to do the same validation server-side!

Comment: In general, I would ask [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), but in this case anything you might have tried will be "wrong" by my definition :p

Comment: What if there is no submit button for OP's case?

Comment: @chris97ong Then the default action is that a form is submitted when pressing Enter, which triggers validation.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery not needed.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="ID">
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("ID").onkeyup = function() {
    var text_content = document.getElementById("ID").value;
    if(/[^\-,0-9]/.test(text_content)) {
        text_content = text_content.substring(0, text_content.length - 1)
        document.getElementById("ID").value = text_content;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEP8p/1/). Hope that was what you were looking for.

Comment: JavaScript isn't needed either :p Also note that your code is not compatible with someone typing in the middle of the text - if I type 123 then go back to the start and type abc, result is abc.